# Latex - How can I use minipage inside longtable?

Tags: latex, longtable

I have a table that I would like to split over pages, but I can't seem to figure out how I can do it with my current lay-out or commands that I use.
At this time, I used landscape and minipage so that it would fit on one page:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{pdflscape} 
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{makecell}


\begin{document}


\begin{landscape}
\centering
\begin{table}[!htb]
\caption{\label{CH2_tab:P80L} Empirical power from the simulation study with the indicators having an overall reliability of 80\% and a linear relationship with the latent variable. The highest power per setting is indicated in bold.}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
\centering

\medskip
\scalebox{0.45}{
\begin{tabular}{rcccccc}
   \hline
 &   \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{Linear}} \\   
\cline{2-7}
&  \makecell{\textbf{WMW -- max rel} } &  \makecell{\textbf{WMW -- mean }} &  \makecell{\textbf{\textit{t} test -- max rel }} &  \makecell{\textbf{\textit{t} test -- mean }} &  \makecell{\textbf{SEM} }  & \makecell{\textbf{SEM -- corrected}}  \\
  \hline
      \multicolumn{7}{l}{$\mathcal{N}(0,1)$} \\
  \multicolumn{7}{l}{\bm{$m=n=15$}} \\
  \hline
  Setting 1 & 29.7 & 31.0 &  \textbf{33.2} & 32.9 & 32.4 & 32.1 \\ 
  Setting 2 & 28.4 & 29.2 & 30.7 &  \textbf{31.3} & 30.0 & 30.3 \\ 
  Setting 3 & 29.5 & 29.3 & 31.8 &  \textbf{32.3} & 32.0 & 31.9 \\ 
  Setting 4 & 25.8 & 26.2 & 28.5 & 27.4 &  \textbf{29.4} & 28.6 \\ 
 \hline 
  \multicolumn{7}{l}{\bm{$m=n=50$}} \\
  \hline
  Setting 1 & 78.7 & 79.1 & 81.7 & 81.4 & \textbf{83.2} & 83.1 \\ 
  Setting 2 & 79.5 & 78.8 & 81.0 & 80.4 & 82.0 & \textbf{82.1} \\ 
  Setting 3 & 79.2 & 79.9 & 81.2 & 81.8 & \textbf{82.2} & 82.0 \\ 
  Setting 4 & 74.8 & 72.3 & 77.6 & 74.4 & \textbf{80.0} & \textbf{80.0} \\ 
   \hline
  \multicolumn{7}{l}{\bm{$m=n=100$}} \\
  \hline
  Setting 1 & 98.2 & 98.1 & 98.5 & 98.6 & \textbf{98.7} & \textbf{98.7} \\ 
  Setting 2 & 97.7 & 97.7 & 98.2 & \textbf{98.3} & \textbf{98.3} & \textbf{98.3} \\ 
  Setting 3 & 97.6 & 97.5 & 98.1 & \textbf{98.2} & \textbf{98.2} & \textbf{98.2} \\ 
  Setting 4 & 97.4 & 95.1 & 98.1 & 95.8 & 98.1 & \textbf{98.2} \\ 
  \hline
  \multicolumn{7}{l}{$t_5$} \\
  \multicolumn{7}{l}{\bm{$m=n=15$}} \\
  \hline
   Setting 1 & 23.5 & 23.9 & 24.2 & 24.1 & \textbf{24.4} & 23.9 \\ 
  Setting 2 & 24.0 & \textbf{24.1} & 23.1 & 22.6 & 22.0 & 22.2 \\ 
  Setting 3 & 23.7 & \textbf{23.8} & 22.4 & 23.1 & 22.5 & 23.3 \\ 
  Setting 4 & 22.1 & 22.4 & 22.2 & 22.4 & 22.4 & \textbf{23.5} \\ 
\hline 
  \multicolumn{7}{l}{\bm{$m=n=50$}} \\
  \hline
  Setting 1 & 65.8 &  \textbf{66.1} & 60.8 & 60.9 & 61.8 & 61.4 \\ 
  Setting 2 &  \textbf{68.7} &  \textbf{68.7} & 62.2 & 62.2 & 63.7 & 63.4 \\ 
  Setting 3 & 67.3 &  \textbf{67.6} & 61.1 & 61.4 & 62.7 & 62.2 \\ 
  Setting 4 &  \textbf{63.9} & 58.4 & 57.6 & 53.7 & 60.2 & 60.0 \\ 
 \hline
  \multicolumn{7}{l}{\bm{$m=n=100$}} \\
  \hline
  Setting 1 & 92.3 &  \textbf{92.4} & 87.6 & 87.6 & 88.0 & 88.1 \\ 
  Setting 2 &  \textbf{91.7} &  \textbf{91.7} & 87.0 & 87.4 & 87.9 & 87.8 \\ 
  Setting 3 & 93.2 &  \textbf{93.4} & 88.9 & 88.7 & 89.4 & 89.5 \\ 
  Setting 4 &  \textbf{90.6} & 86.8 & 85.7 & 83.4 & 87.4 & 87.4 \\ 
 \hline
   \hline
   \end{tabular}
}

\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
\centering

\medskip

\scalebox{0.45}{
\begin{tabular}{rcccccc}
   \hline
 &   \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{Linear}} \\   
\cline{2-7}
&  \makecell{\textbf{WMW -- max rel} } &  \makecell{\textbf{WMW -- mean }} &  \makecell{\textbf{\textit{t} test -- max rel }} &  \makecell{\textbf{\textit{t} test -- mean }} &  \makecell{\textbf{SEM} }  & \makecell{\textbf{SEM -- corrected}}  \\
  \hline
    \multicolumn{7}{l}{$Laplace(0,1.25)$} \\
  \multicolumn{7}{l}{\bm{$m=n=15$}} \\
  \hline
  Setting 1 & 21.5 & \textbf{22.3} & 19.6 & 20.4 & 19.3 & 19.0 \\ 
  Setting 2 & \textbf{21.9} & 21.4 & 21.0 & 21.1 & 19.8 & 21.0 \\ 
  Setting 3 & 22.0 & \textbf{22.5} & 20.6 & 20.3 & 20.1 & 20.3 \\ 
  Setting 4 & 17.3 & \textbf{19.8} & 16.5 & 18.8 & 19.4 & 19.3 \\ 
    \hline 
  \multicolumn{7}{l}{\bm{$m=n=50$}} \\
  \hline
  Setting 1 & 61.8 & \textbf{62.0} & 53.2 & 53.2 & 55.0 & 54.6 \\ 
  Setting 2 & 62.2 & \textbf{63.2} & 52.7 & 53.3 & 54.5 & 53.8 \\ 
  Setting 3 & 64.6 & \textbf{66.0} & 52.9 & 52.8 & 54.7 & 54.2 \\ 
  Setting 4 & \textbf{58.9} & 56.9 & 51.7 & 49.8 & 56.0 & 56.1 \\ 
 \hline
  \multicolumn{7}{l}{\bm{$m=n=100$}} \\
  \hline
  Setting 1 & \textbf{92.3} & 92.2 & 83.2 & 82.9 & 83.5 & 83.4 \\ 
  Setting 2 & \textbf{88.1} & 87.9 & 77.7 & 77.5 & 78.2 & 78.1 \\ 
  Setting 3 & \textbf{91.0} & 90.7 & 82.6 & 82.9 & 82.9 & 83.0 \\ 
  Setting 4 & \textbf{85.5} & 80.4 & 77.7 & 74.2 & 79.3 & 79.3 \\
  \hline
  \multicolumn{7}{l}{Exp} \\
  \multicolumn{7}{l}{\bm{$m=n=15$}} \\
  \hline
  Setting 1 & 22.2 & \textbf{23.1} & 18.1 & 18.2 & 18.7 & 18.3 \\ 
  Setting 2 & 19.7 & \textbf{19.8} & 17.0 & 17.5 & 17.2 & 17.5 \\ 
  Setting 3 & 19.4 & \textbf{20.2} & 16.9 & 17.6 & 16.9 & 17.0 \\ 
  Setting 4 & 15.7 & \textbf{16.0} & 13.4 & 14.9 & 14.8 & 14.9 \\ 
  \hline 
  \multicolumn{7}{l}{\bm{$m=n=50$}} \\
  \hline
  Setting 1 & 61.9 & \textbf{62.0} & 40.8 & 41.8 & 42.6 & 42.6 \\ 
  Setting 2 & 56.2 & \textbf{57.6} & 38.0 & 38.2 & 39.9 & 39.3 \\ 
  Setting 3 & 63.0 & \textbf{63.5} & 42.6 & 42.6 & 44.9 & 44.8 \\ 
  Setting 4 & \textbf{50.1} & 45.0 & 36.9 & 36.7 & 40.6 & 40.4 \\ 
 \hline
  \multicolumn{7}{l}{\bm{$m=n=100$}} \\
  \hline
  Setting 1 & 86.7 & \textbf{87.2} & 67.2 & 67.5 & 67.7 & 67.8 \\ 
  Setting 2 & 85.4 & \textbf{85.6} & 65.5 & 66.0 & 66.6 & 66.8 \\ 
  Setting 3 & 88.2 & \textbf{88.4} & 66.4 & 66.3 & 67.3 & 67.6 \\ 
  Setting 4 & \textbf{83.5} & 76.1 & 65.2 & 61.1 & 66.9 & 67.7 \\ 
  \hline
   \hline
   \end{tabular}
} 

\end{minipage}\hfill
\end{table}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

However, I would like to split this table nicely over multiple pages (and thus by using e.g. longtable), in such way that on one page, I have the results for the N(0,1) and Laplace distribution (side by side), and then on the second page the t_5 and Exp distribution (side by side), i.e. split each table over 2 pages, but have 2 tables side by side by using minipage inside long table.

I know I could converge them and just make one large table and then use long table, however, I would really like not to rewrite the code (since I have 10 more tables like this). Does someone know how I could do this? I tried several ways, but none of them produce the result I am looking for.

Thank you for all your feedback!

Heidelinde

Comment: I think rewriting the code to be in a single table is your best bet. Also don't use `\scalebox` on content which contains text. Better use a suitable font size instead - this will make the result much easier to read.

Comment: or totally different approach: forgo all these minipages and stuff and put only one page in full size on each page. Then use something like `pgfpages` to put two of these pages besides each other.